# Bash commands in Makefile

Tags: mac, bash, shell, makefile

I want to use bash commands in Makefile along with MATLAB scripts. Currently when i put a simple bash command in Makefile and run that target, I get error

> /bin/bash: ./test1: No such file or directory

I have used a simple bash command

```
satuaratedrate:
bash -c "cd ~/Desktop/r4/saturatedrate/iperf_s"; echo "I'm in some_dir"; ./test1; echo "is it working"
```

I have also put `SHELL := /bin/bash`in beginning of make file as suggested by [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets)

I am using Mac OsX

Comment: Give a look to some tutorial on the net about how to create a makefile. [E.g. here](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html). Take a working makefile and modify it. Usually it's more cosy. BTW post your whole makefile file so it will be possible to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semi-colon will terminate a bash command. So 
`bash -c "cd ~/Desktop/r4/saturatedrate/iperf_s";`  starts a bash shell and does the `cd` command then exits. Then the echo command and then the test1 command - but test1 does not exist in the current directory. Remember the shell command that issued the `cd` command has exited.

This make command should call test1:

```
saturatedrate:
    bash -c "cd ~/Desktop/r4/saturatedrate/iperf_s/test1";
```

Comment: when i try this command test1 which is placed in 'code'~/Desktop/r4/saturatedrate/iperf_s is run the current directory from where the command is run. I want the test1 to run in this directory "~/Desktop/r4/saturatedrate/iperf_s/"

Comment: `bash -c "cd ~/Desktop/r4/saturatedrate/iperf_s && ./test1"` is working @suspectus, Thank you so much

Comment: @Umar - Glad to hear you have it working now.